# how to concat rules for the same AR model in Yii

Tags: php, class, yii

I use `Yii MVC`.

I have to add new columns in a data table very often.

I want to use `Gii` and regenerate the `model` and keep the chnages that i made; changes like constants, variables, rules, relations, etc ...

So, let's take for example the `url` class model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "url".
 *
 * The followings are the` available columns in table 'url':
 * @property string $id
 * @property integer $instance_id
 * @property integer $website_id
 * @property string $link
 * @property string $title
 * @property integer $created
 * @property integer $updated
 * @property integer $status
 */
class Url extends CActiveRecord {

    const ACTIVE = 1;

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Url the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName() {
        return 'url';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('instance_id, website_id, link, title, created, updated, status', 'required'),
            array('instance_id, website_id, created, updated, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('link, title', 'length', 'max' => 255),
            array('link', 'unique'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, instance_id, website_id, link, title, created, updated, status', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'instance_id' => 'Instance',
            'website_id' => 'Website',
            'link' => 'Link',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'updated' => 'Updated',
            'status' => 'Status',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('instance_id', $this->instance_id);
        $criteria->compare('website_id', $this->website_id);
        $criteria->compare('link', $this->link, true);
        $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created);
        $criteria->compare('updated', $this->updated);
        $criteria->compare('status', $this->status);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

}
```

when I will regenerate the `model`, the `const` and the `rule` with `unique` will be lost

so, I created a new `model class`, `UrlM`, that extends the `url` model class, and this class keps all my enhancements:

```
<?php

class UrlM extends Url {

    const ACTIVE = 1;

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('link', 'unique'),
        );
    }

    public function relations() {
        return array(
        );
    }

}
```

how do i concat the rules from the `url` model class with the `rules` from the `urlm` model class?

the same answer should aply for future enhancements, like `relations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each function of the parent class - like `rules()`, `relations()` etc., returns array. So you may use call to the `parent::rules()` and then just join "array".

```
public function rules() {
  $myParentRules=parent::rules();
  $myConcatRules=$myParentRules + array(
    array('link', 'unique'),
  );
  return $myConcatRules;
}
```

Comment: the + operator does not work, using merge, forks perfect, 10x

Answer (score 0):

array_merge will help you.

```
    public function rules() {
    $myRules = array(
        array('id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
    );

    return array_merge(parent::rules(),$myRules);

}
```